# Why should i wrap my document in <html> tags?

Tags: html

As far as I can work out, surrounding my code in html tags, does the same thing as !DOCTYPE html, so why should I use them.

Is:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
...
</html>
```

The same as:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
...
```

I have tried a few different sites, and they are all identical when I remove the HTML tags.  These sites contain numerous different languages, PHP JavaScript and a few others, but none seem affected.

I was surprised that no one has already asked this question, as it seems fairly obvious.

I realise that html tags are used to tell the browser how to render a page, but that is the job of the `<!DOCTYPE...>`.

I have tried googling (is that how you say it?) and found nothing, except a comment that they should be used, but no explanation.

This seems like a simple question, but I feel may have a more in-depth answer.

Thanks for any help you can give.

Comment: Web browsers are extremely fault tolerant.

Comment: you can miss also the HEAD, BODY, because browsers are tolerant, but it is not a good practice to slip them

Comment: Requirement-wise, you only *have* to explicitly write the `<html>` tags if you're writing XHTML, not HTML. They're otherwise, for all intents and purposes, optional. It's entirely valid to leave them out, as long as you make sure there is no garbage around the doctype. Personally, I write them because I just like being explicit with my markup.

Comment: Thanks for the feedback, can someone tell me why the downvote, without any reason given?

Comment: you can miss the close of <p> or <a> tags on most browsers, because they are tolerant, but do not abuse their tolerance!

Comment: @AdrianWragg so it is, i could not find this, as it is such an old post, thanks for letting me know, i would remove, but the answer is valid, so i will leave for now

Comment: @FélixGagnon-Grenier I know what you mean, it does seem like a simple question, and would pro downvode if i just read the title.

Comment: @florin.prisecariu - The ability to omit the end tag for `p` elements is not because of tolerance, but because the specification explicitly permits them to be omitted and provides rules to determine where the element ends when there is no explicit end tag.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The HTML start tag and end tag are (by specification) optional, so they have little practical use (assuming you aren't working in XML) other than to stop people who don't know they are optional thinking of badly of you.

You do need a start tag in order to have attributes on an element though, and you *should* specify the language the document is written in with a `lang` attribute.

Answer (score 1):

The HTML tag is an optional tag i.e. you can have it or not have it unless the first element is a comment. There are other optional tags like BODY and HEAD and there are conditions on their optionality.

http://www.w3.org/TR/html-markup/html.html

http://www.w3.org/TR/html-markup/body.html
http://www.w3.org/TR/html-markup/head.html

Comment: Thanks, i was wondering about the other tags like head and body.